# Anyone has the same problem with Git in Intellij 2020.2?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

[image: screenshot]

```
Git is not installed
Unsupported format of git --version output: [0x7FFFBB83E044] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)
git version 2.29.0.windows.1
```

Can't use git in Intellij. Probably the reason with the new format of git --version output. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you start the IDE? Try running it via JetBrains ToolBox. Does calling /usr/bin/git on the command line work?

Comment: See also https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6391

Comment: using git via command line works. I opened the idea via desktop shortcut.I was really confused because the embedded git tool in IDEA actually worked few minutes ago. I don't know whether it is caused by the Windows update, idea update or the git update

Comment: Try running IDE from ToolBox, or directly by running `idea.sh`/`idea64.exe`

Comment: solved, I rolled back the Windows update